# How to use objects.filter for (one-to-many) releation

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 tables: Job, Flight, and Image
One job can have multiple flights and a flight can have only one job. And a flight can have many images.
I get all flights related to the job using the query:

```
flights = Flight.objects.filter(job_id=job_id)
```

and now I want all images in those flights to call a function for all images but I couldn't implement it without a loop:

```
for flight in flights:
        images = Image.objects.filter(flight=flight)
        data = process_images(images)
```

I want something like:

```
images = Image.objects.filter(flight=flights)
```

so I call `process_images` only once, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `__` to follow a `Foreign Key` relationship.

```
images = Image.objects.filter(flight__job_id=job_id)
```